# Django Rest Framework SlugRelatedField: field may not be null

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF for API requests. I have a serializer which is serializing several fields. Some of the fields I have is are `SlugRelatedField`. These fields have `allow_null=True` as not all requests will have all fields posted.

The issue I am having is, when I have `many=True` the `allow_null` does not seem to work. I get the following error `"tag":["This field may not be null."]`

```
tag = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    queryset=Tag.objects.all(),
    many=True,
    required=False,
    allow_null=True,
    slug_field="name"
)
```

Anyone able to assist?

Comment: don't send null. send an empty list `[]` it will not give error. and remove `allow_null`

Comment: @zaphod100.10 Thanks

Comment: glad to be of help! Please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't send null. send an empty list `[]` it will not give error. and remove `allow_null`